# fstab mount, boot stuck on "A start job is running for dev-disk-by\..."

Tags: boot, fstab

I am running debian 8.1 and working on this for hours now! I try to auto mount `seagate` and `medion` on boot if they are plugged in, but if the server is booting without one of these `LABEL`s it stucks here for 1:30min and boots into maintainace mode:

```
Give root password for maintenace
(or type Control-D to continue):
```

I just want to mount my usb devices if they are present.. : /

[image]

**/etc/fstab:**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.

#FIXED
#<file system>                             <mount point>   <type>   <options>           <dump>   <pass>
UUID=f243951c-f61c-4af7-88c5-79ba0a33caf8  /               ext4     errors=remount-ro   0        1
UUID=28737539-1569-4db7-9ea3-d74473502f39  none            swap     sw                  0        0

#REMOVABLE
#<file system>   <mount point>   <type>    <options>                    <dump>   <pass>
#LABEL=medion     /mnt/medion     ntfs-3g   rw,noauto,nobootwait,nofail  0        2
LABEL=seagate    /mnt/seagate    ntfs-3g   rw,nobootwait,nofail         0        2
```

Comment: I can't find this `nobootwait` in the man pages. Apparently it is Ubuntu-specific. Your best option is probably to use `noauto` and add some rules in udev.conf (I'm not sure how to write them so I keep this as a comment instead of an answer)

Comment: There was a time in which it worked perfectly only with fstab..

Comment: @8m47x - make sure you've got the ntfs-3g modules and fsck programs in initramfs. Else you can symlink `/bin/true` to `/bin/fsck.ntfs`, but a quick `man` scan showed up `ntfsprogs` for me which lists a command-line application named `ntfsfix` which at least sounds like it would be better suited to the task.

Comment: A system will attempt to search for the disk for a while if it cannot be found (I don't know exactly why, but can hazard a guess that in case it needs to spin up, etc). However, I would follow the answer below and try to put a `0` for the `pass` option, as is for your swap partition.

Answer (score 2):

Add the (previously documented but unimplemented) option `nofail`.

> $ man fstab
>
> `nofail` do not report errors for this device if it does not exist.

See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/638985/how-to-configure-systemd-to-ignore-fstab-drive-mount-failures

> But also add a low timeout with something like `x-systemd.device-timeout=2`, because the default timeout seems to be 90 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

According to the fstab man-page you can skip the fsck for specific mounts if you put "0" as the last digit, instead of "2" in /etc/fstab.

( For some reason for me the "0" was ignored for my usb-drive I mounted via UUID ... however it may not hurt to take a try. )